# Can I add a field to an existing struct with Go?

Tags: go

Suppose I have the struct

```
type Planet struct {
    Name       string  `json:"name"`
    Aphelion   float64 `json:"aphelion"`   // in million km
    Perihelion float64 `json:"perihelion"` // in million km
    Axis       int64   `json:"Axis"`       // in km
    Radius     float64 `json:"radius"`
}
```

as well as instances of this struct, e.g.

```
var mars = new(Planet)
mars.Name = "Mars"
mars.Aphelion = 249.2
mars.Perihelion = 206.7
mars.Axis = 227939100
mars.Radius = 3389.5

var earth = new(Planet)
earth.Name = "Earth"
earth.Aphelion = 151.930
earth.Perihelion = 147.095
earth.Axis = 149598261
earth.Radius = 6371.0

var venus = new(Planet)
venus.Name = "Venus"
venus.Aphelion = 108.939
venus.Perihelion = 107.477
venus.Axis = 108208000
venus.Radius = 6051.8
```

Now I want to add a field, e.g. `Mass` to all of those. How can I do that?

At the moment, I define a new struct, e.g. `PlanetWithMass` and reassign all fields - field by field - to new instances of the `PlanetWithMass`.

Is there a less verbose way to do it? A way which does not need adjustment when `Planet` changes?

edit: I need this on a web server, where I have to send the struct as JSON, but with an additional field. Embedding does not solve this problem as it changes the resulting JSON.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You could embed `Planet` into `PlanetWithMass`:

```
type PlanetWithMass struct {
    Planet
    Mass float64
}
```

and do something like

```
marsWithMass := PlanetWithMass{
    Planet: mars,
    Mass: 639e21,
}
```

For more info on embedding, see the [Spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types) and [Effective Go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#embedding).

➜ [Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/NuPIlrmYJM)

Comment: Ok, but when I send this as a JSON object it is something completely different. I need a JSON object with one additional field.

Comment: No, I need `{"name": "mars", "aphelion": "12.123",..., "mass": "639e21"}`, but your code will give me `{"planet": {"name": "mars", "aphelion": "12.123",...,}, "mass": "639e21"}`. That is the problem.

Comment: @moose: no it doesn't. Planet needs to be anonymous in PlanetWithMass: http://play.golang.org/p/vfe9PJdVXy

Comment: @JimB That comment was important :-) Could you please add it to your answer? It was the reason why I did not get the result I wanted

Comment: @moose: I don't understand, it is in Simon's answer. He mentioned embedding twice, gave to links to the documentation, and provided an example.

Comment: @JimB The problem was that I added `json:"planets"`. I simply had to remove this.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably use **map[string]string** which will enable you to explicitly add as many sub keys as possible. NOTE: You will have to declare the struct first with one type

`type PlanetWithMass struct { Planet map[string]string }`

Then to add more fields, start by an instance of the struct

```
type PlanetWithMass struct {
  Planet map[string]string
}

planet := &PlanetWithMass{} // instance of struct

planet.Planet = make(map[string]string) // declare field as a map[string]string

planet.Planet["Name"] = "Mercury"
planet.Planet["Galaxy"] = "Milky Way"
planet.Planet["Population"] = "7 Billion"
planet.Planet["HasOceans"] = "Yes"
```

Using this method, you can add several fields to the struct without the worry of using interfaces. It might be a round hack but it works!