# Can I add a field to an interface using a struct?

Tags: json, go

I came across an interesting scenario. I had a struct and I want to add a field message to it. I was able to do this by going through [Can I add a field to an existing struct with Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29019864/can-i-add-a-field-to-an-existing-struct-with-go).

```
type User struct {
 // user fields here
}

type UpdationResponse struct {
 User
 Message string `json:"message,omitempty"` 
}

func SendSuccessResponse(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, resp interface{}) interface{} {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    return json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(resp)
}
```

This returns a JSON like

```
{
    "id": "50",
    "firstName": "vibhor",
    "lastName": "agrawal",
    "email": "someemail@emailprovider.com",
    "isVerified": false,
    "joinedAt": "2020-06-28T09:45:59Z",
    "fullName": "vibhor agrawal"
    "message": "Profile Updated."
}
```

So, this helps me in sending the User data along with a message let's say "Profile Updated.". If I want to generalize this for all my APIs. Is there something I can do.

I tried:

```
type SuccessResponse struct {
 Data    interface{}
 Message string `json:"message,omitempty"`
}

func SendSuccessResponse(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, resp SuccessResponse) interface{} {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    return json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(resp)
}
```

But when I send it as JSON it makes a structure like

```
{
    "Data": {
        "id": "50",
        "firstName": "vibhor",
        "lastName": "agrawal",
        "email": "someemail@emailprovider.com",
        "isVerified": false,
        "joinedAt": "2020-06-28T09:45:59Z",
        "fullName": "vibhor agrawal"
    },
    "message": "Profile Updated."
}
```

Is there a way I can add message in the data itself and generalize this for all my success responses irrespective of `Data`?

Comment: What you're asking for is unclear. Show what you want the output to be and how you would use it.

Comment: @Marc does this help?

Comment: Responding to your title: "Can I add a field to an interface?" -- Interfaces don't have fields at all, so no, you cannot add fields to interfaces. But that doesn't seem very related to your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short: This is not possible.

Long answer:

In your first example the struct `UpdationResponse` extends the struct `User`. This is also called a mixin. Simply speaking `UpdationResponse` takes all attributes of `User` and uses them itself.

In your second example the struct `SuccessResponse` defines the attribute `Data` which can be anything. `Data` is a child element of `SuccessResponse` and gets marshalled as such. There is no way around it, as go source code is statically typed and compiled ahead of time.

Answer (score 3):

You could have the response implement the `json.Marshaler` interface, have it marshal the two fields separately and then merge the results at the end.

```
func (r Response) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    out1, err := json.Marshal(r.Data)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    type _Response Response // to avoid infinite recursion
    out2, err := json.Marshal((_Response)(r))
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    // NOTE: this may need more work to handle other cases, for example
    // the Data field's dynamic type being a slice of some type, rather than
    // a single struct....
    if size := len(out1); size > 0 && out1[size-1] == '}' {
        if size > 2 {
            out1[size-1] = ',' // replace "}" with ","
        } else {
            out1 = out1[:size-1] // drop "}"
        }

        out2 = out2[1:]              // drop "{"
        out := append(out1, out2...) // merge
        return out, nil
    }

    return out2, nil
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/9u0jcEgt2zL